# Optimizing MySQL queries for reporting

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, reporting

I am currently working on writing some Stored Procedures using MySQL 5.7. These stored procedures usually join on tables having 1 - 2 million records and output the records as per the filters selected on front - end by users.

The Stored Procedures have a pagination logic which currently works like this -

1. Create a temporary table with all data from joins and filtering the data using `find_in_set` in where clause followed with Order By clause on the required column.

```
Create temp table Temp AS (
SELECT my req columns
FROM table
# all joins #
WHERE # filters #
Order by columns);
```

2. Once I have all data in temporary table, I do this:

```
SET InitialRowCount = (case when PageSize = 0 then 0 else (PageNumber - 1) * FinalPageSize END);
```

```
SELECT columns
FROM TempTable
LIMIT InitialRowCount , FinalPageSize;
```

Using this approach I have to always pull all data irrespective of page number/page size requested and creating a temporary table with the given filters.

I wanted to know if there is a approach where I can make my query pull like this:

```
User Request - 
Name - matt, john
Last Login - mydate
order by column - last name
page number - 2
page size 30

What I would like to happen -
Select columns
from 
#all joins here#
WHERE Clause
Order By Last Name
AND GIVE Page Number 2 with 30 records
```

I don't want to pull all records always and store in the temporary table. I just want to query the required records.
Currently I cannot use the above logic in query directly as I don't have a primary key which can be used like:

```
WHERE pk > initial row count
AND LIMIT pagesize
```

Comment: Doesn't it work if you replace your 
`AND GIVE Page Number 2 with 30 records` by `LIMIT 30 OFFSET (PageNumber-1)*30` (assuming PageNumber starts at 1)

Comment: @Pepper So my temporary table has a primary key `id` using which I can do:
```WHERE id > Initial Row Count Limit pagesize```
Also using ```LIMIT x, y``` is very slow

Comment: Ok, I understand the issue now, but i'm not really in any capacity to help, however, sorry :<